# Chrome extension CSP remote script not loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to include a remote script in my web extension. I'd like to use it in various parts of my extension: background script, content script, and browser actions, but CSP keeps blocking me. I've tried all the solutions I can find, but nothing seems to work. I've updated my CSP in `manifest.json` to include the src. Here's what I'm doing

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "author": "me",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.1.1",

  "description": "the description",

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'",

  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/trust-nobody-v2-16.png",
    "48": "icons/trust-nobody-v2-48.png",
    "128": "icons/trust-nobody-v2-128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["*://*/*", "tabs", "storage", "alarms"],

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "myid@my.id"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"],
      "css": ["content-script.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://unpkg.com/js-logger/src/logger.min.js"
    ></script>

    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="settings">Settings</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I go to my popup I get this in the

```
Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/js-logger/src/logger.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: It's a terrible idea to load a network script into the super privileged context of an extension. Don't ever do it. Download the code and load it as a normal script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that, but I'd still like to get this working for local development.

Comment: Did you reload the extension after editing manifest.json?

Comment: Yes I reloaded the extension after editing manifest.json.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because of a network redirect. Try loading the final tagged URL like `https://unpkg.com/js-logger@1.6.1/src/logger.min.js` which is what you should be doing anyway because this way things won't break unexpectedly on update.

Comment: I just gave that a try as well. It didn't work.